# Why has none of the styling worked on this p?

Tags: html, css

I've stared quite a bit and can't see the mistake. Live [here](http://moonwards.com/), line 238 in css, 41 in html.

css:

```
.highlight {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.2);
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

html

```
<p class="highlight, col-4, col-m-4">
        What would it <span style="color: yellow;">really</span> be like to live 
        on the Moon?
     </p>
```

Comment: @m69 yeah, that's it. I was thinking of css, where if you don't put commas, then you are saying the 2nd element is the child of the 1st selector. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of `,`:

```
<p class="highlight col-4 col-m-4">
```

class attribute can contain letters `[A–Z]` and `[a–z]`, digits `[0–9]` and `_`, `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't use "," while adding multiple class names.

just use space to separate single class names.

```
`<p class="highlight col-4 col-m-4">
    What would it <span style="color: yellow;">really</span> be like to live 
    on the Moon?
 </p>`
```